# Solved: Can no longer start Tor on macOS High Sierra 10.13 since upgrading to 7.0.8

Tags: mac

**Update**: I fixed the problem. The crucial step after deleting the app and the `TorBrowser-Data` folder was rebooting my Mac before re-installing. After that, everything worked just fine.

---

I've been using Tor fine for many weeks since upgrading my Mac to High Sierra 10.13.

Today, I asked Tor to check for updates, and I was told of the 7.0.8 update. I clicked to upgrade, but upon restarting was shown the following error:

> Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you restart Tor, the Tor Browser will not be able to reach any websites. If the problem persists, please send a copy of your Tor Log to the support team.

Clicking the "Restart Tor" button brings the same dialog back.

I've uninstalled Tor and removed my `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data` folder, emptied my trash, and re-installed - but I get the same error.

I've also tried removing the app & `TorBrowser-Data` folder and reinstalling v6.08, v7.07, and even v7.56a6 - yet every time I start them, I get the same error.

Attempting to copy the Tor log to the clipboard always shows that there are 0 logs copied.

If removing the app and data folders isn't enough, what on earth could be causing this?

Thanks!

[image: The error dialog]

Comment: Well - I should have tried this before posting.
 
The solution?
 
After deleting the app and the `TorBrowser-Data` folder, I rebooted before re-installing.
 
After that, everything worked just fine.

Comment: I haven't the TorBrowser Folder on Library/Application Support. Do you have any idea where it can be? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried to delete all and reboot my Mac but always the same bug when I try to launch Tor. Can someone help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: exit tor, open activity monitor and kill processes; 'Tor Browser' and 'tor.real'.. worked for me.